# Python: set axis scale in canvas

Tags: python

In Python, using the canvas module, how do I make a canvas in which the x-axis starts at 0?
I can make a script which draws the gridlines at 0, but the actual canvas still goes from -10 to 10

I'm talking about an asymetrical layout here. I can set the minimum x to be 0, but that only works if the maximum x is 0 as well. What I'm trying to do is making a graph in [0, 10]

Answer (score 0):

If you [look at the code](https://github.com/mdipierro/canvas/blob/master/canvas.py), you'll see that the the `__init__` function takes a parameter `xrange`, which is used to set the limits of the x-axis. Just initialize your object with the range you need:

```
c = Canvas(xrange=(0, 10))
```